# Pandas select columns using list but ignore missing column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
    'A'   'B'   'C'   'X'   ,'Y'    ,  'Z'
0   
1
2
3
4
5
```

and a list `l=[A,B,C,D,E,F]`

I want to use that that list to select columns that are in the list but ignore the ones that don't appear.

So the expected output is

```
  'A'   'B'   'C'  
0   
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting pandas dataframe column by list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40636514/selecting-pandas-dataframe-column-by-list)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select all rows by `:` and columns by mask created by [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) :

```
df = df.loc[:, df.columns.isin(l)]
```

Or get columns names by [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
df = df[df.columns.intersection(l)]
```

---

```
print (df)
    A   B   C
0 NaN NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN NaN
3 NaN NaN NaN
4 NaN NaN NaN
5 NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: perfect, thanks :)

Comment: To note, that intersection internally operates on sets, so the column sequence may be perturbed.