# PANDAS Index specific columns corresponds to strings in a list

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a Pandas dataframe which has several columns and a list. If a want to index the columns which are the same as the elements in the list one by one(for example, first the 'apple' column then the 'grape' column), how can I realize this?
It does not work if I use code like fruits[list[0]], only fruits['apple'] works.

```
columns = ['apple', 'mango', 'pear','grape','number']
fruits = pd.read_csv('fruit', names=columns)
list = ['apple','grape']
```

Comment: first don't use the variable name as list. second `fruit.loc[:, li]` or `fruit[li]`  `li` is here your `list` variable.

Comment: Does [Selecting columns by list (and columns are subset of list)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40636514/selecting-columns-by-list-and-columns-are-subset-of-list) answer your question?

Comment: Or: [Pandas select columns using list but ignore missing column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61305921/pandas-select-columns-using-list-but-ignore-missing-column-names),

Answer (score 0):

The loc method lets you filter based on any of the dimensions of a dataframe. In your case you want to selected based on the column name, which is the second dimension. The ':' character indicates take all the values from this dimension.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

Try:

```
columns = ['apple', 'mango', 'pear','grape','number']
fruits = pd.read_csv('fruit', names=columns)
list_fruits = ['apple','grape']

for fruitname in list_fruits:
    column = list_fruits.loc[:, fruitname]
```